# Building an Autocomplete Form Element with Atlas Search and Django

Tags: javascript, django, mongodb, autocomplete

I want to build an autocomplete form in a Django webapp. I have already been able to do the search bar where I query my MongoDB database but how can I add an autocomplete? I tried to adapt [an official tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IDlOI0D8-8&ab_channel=MongoDB) that does it with Javascript:

`search_similar.html`:

```
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="recommendations">
    <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
    <div class="form">
      <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
        <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
        <input id="perfumename" type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" autocomplete="nope"/>
      </form>
      <form class="login-form" action = "similar_results/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="perfume name"/> <!-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRODv6UTXpM&ab_channel=ProgrammingKnowledge -->
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="perfumename2" type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" autocomplete="nope"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#perfumename").autocomplete({
          source: async function(request, response){
            let data=await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/search_similar?q={request.term}`)
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => results.map(result => {
              return { label: result.name, value: result.name, id:result._id };
            }
            response(data);
          },
          minLength=2,
          select: function(event, ui){
            console.log(ui.item);
          }

        })
      }),
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#perfumename2").autocomplete({
          source: async function(request, response){
            let data=await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/search_similar?q={request.term}`)
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => results.map(result => {
              return { label: result.name, value: result.name, id:result._id };
            }
            response(data);
          },
          minLength=2,
          select: function(event, ui){
            console.log(ui.item);
          }

        })
      })
    </script>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Even when I have `autocomplete="nope"` the first search bar still shows up the default autocomplete by chrome and doesn't show up the one I built in MongoDB. The second doesn't show up anything, even when I link the id to the script.

[image]

Comment: `<input id="perfumename" type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" autocomplete="off"/>` to disable browser's autocompletion. You still need javascript for mongodb-driven autocompletion.

Comment: @AlexBlex I added it but it still returns the browser autocompletion. And the autocomplete isn't the MongoDB one yet

Comment: Ah, sorry missed the browser name. It's an old issue with Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914451 Try different values like `autocomplete="nope"`

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks! It works, but only for the first search bar, not the second ...

Comment: But you don't have autocompletion for the second field in your code. It's not gonna work until you program it to work.

Comment: @AlexBlex Even if I change `$("#perfumename").autocomplete` with `$("#perfumename2").autocomplete`?

Comment: If you change it you will lose autocompletion for the first field. If you need it for both, you need js to be triggered for both fields =)

Comment: @AlexBlex Okay, I added a second function in the <script> but that doesn't trigger any autocomplete suggestion yet...

Comment: Check if you have any errors in javascript, check if autocomplete sends expected http requests to the back in the networks tab in the chrome devtools. Debug.